# Textbox as Input in an SQL Query in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a database in Microsoft Access 2010 involving records of employees. One of my macros involves running the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    *

FROM
    Employees

WHERE
    [First Name] = [Enter First Name]
    AND [Last Name] = [Enter Last Name];
```

Currently running the query results in 2 dialog windows popping up to enter the first and last name. This works as intended, but I want to bind the query to a button in my database next to some text boxes, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szh0o.png), so that when I click on the blue button it runs the query with the text boxes as the first and last name inputs. I'd like to not get too deep into VBA if I can help it, as I haven't had any experience coding in it.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/113352     AND   http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm couple of seconds on google "how to reference a form in query"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No code needed - as @Nathan_Sav said a - a quick search will find what you're after (I find "reference main form from subform" gives the best page at the top - http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm )

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE [First Name]=Forms![Form1]![txtFirstName] AND 
      [Last Name]=Forms![Form1]![txtLastName]
```

txtFirstName & txtLastName are the names I gave to the text controls on Form1.

Edit: Your macro button can then just open the query.