# SQL in VBA - Recording user input in variable.

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a query that allows the user to input a parameter (i.e. "John Smith" and returns the results on a form. The SQL:

```
SELECT Database.Contact_ID, Database.[Full Name], Institution.Institution, 
Database.Email, Database.[Email 2], Database.[Work phone], Database.[Work 
phone 2], Database.Mobile

FROM Institution INNER JOIN [Database] ON Institution.ID = Database.InstitutionLookup

WHERE (((Database.[Full Name]) Like "*" & [Enter Name] & "*"));
```

I want to show that input on the results form. I've looked into placing the SQL into a VBA module and saving the input as a variable though I'm getting a lot of run-time errors when I do this.

Can this be done purely in the SQL or is the best option to use VBA and/or Macro?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Show the code that you've used and is generating errors. You'll get much better answers than if you leave us to guess.

Comment: What is [Enter Name]?You need to use a property name that corresponds to the input field on the form, something like inputName, try to avoid blanks and keywords in textbox name. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057414/textbox-as-input-in-an-sql-query-in-access

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, posting my answer in case it helps anyone else.

In the end the easiest option was to create a new pop-out form with a single unbound text box. The user inputs their search in here and the query is changed to use this input for the WHERE clause. This then lets me display that input on the form with the query results.

There was only a slight change needed in the SQL:

```
SELECT Database.Contact_ID, Database.[Full Name], Institution.Institution, 
Database.Email, Database.[Email 2], Database.[Work phone], Database.[Work phone 2], 
Database.Mobile

FROM Institution INNER JOIN [Database] ON Institution.ID = Database.InstitutionLookup

WHERE ((Database.[Full Name]) Like "*" & Forms![Contact Search Mk 2]![Enter Name] & *");
```